# Iterador em padrão MVC

Tags: java, mvc

Estou fazendo um projeto e nele foi solicitada a construção de uma classe Iterador. Todo esse projeto está sendo construído com base no padrão MVC. Sendo assim, o que seria essa classe Iterador e como eu vou usá-la? Pelo q eu andei pesquisando parece ter alguma utilidade na implementação de estruturas (listas, pilhas etc), mas não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Acho que esse Iterador tem nada haver com o padrão MVC, apenas uma regra de negocio do projeto que está construindo. Não é mais facil perguntar pro pessoal daí?

Comment: coloque mais detalhes na sua explicação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um Iterador ou Iterator, é utilizado para verificar e percorrer estruturas de dados, como mencionou, Listas, Pilhas, Filas, Conjuntos, Arvore, em um iterador você vai implementar verificações para saber se existe mais elementos dentro da estrutura, método para retornar um elemento dessa estrutura e etc.

A maioria ou se não todas linguagens de programação já vem com estruturas prontas e implementadas para o desenvolvedor apenas fazer uso, caso for realizar as implementações de um Iterador manualmente , fará uso de Arrays construindo a lógica em cada método necessário, deixando o mais dinamico possivel para que as listas possam crescer e diminuir conforme o uso.

O Iterador não deve ter nenhuma conexão com padrão arquitetural MVC, é possivel que tenha visto algo referente a camadas pela divisão de responsabilidade ao implementar o Iterador em diferentes estruturas de dados, ainda assim parece improvável.